# Как записать и прочитать разнотипные бинарные данные в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binary

Работаю с WebSockets, протокол чужого приложения требует использование бинарного формата данных. В числе них есть как Long(64) Int(32) Byte(8) и строки переменной длинны, в начале которых стоит их размер. Каким образом все это можно реализовать на JavaScript?
С контролем LittleEddian/BigEddian и без необходимости ручного прописывания индекса. Пробую использовать DataView, но он неудобен

```
    function send(message) {
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(1024);
    var output = new DataView(buffer);
    output.setInt32(4,677556);
    output.setInt32(0,0);
    output.setInt32(8,0);
    output.setInt32(12,0);
    output.setInt32(16,5);
  if (!window.WebSocket) { return; }
  if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
    socket.send(buffer);
  } else {
    alert("The socket is not open.");
  }
}
```

Comment: используется какая-то библиотека для работы с WebSpckets? Уже есть попытки запросов/приемов? Какие-нибудь результаты?

Comment: @Grundy добавил в текст вопроса. Библиотеки не использую, так что не принципиально какую библиотеку выбрать

Comment: Попробуй [вот тут осмотреть](https://blog.mgechev.com/2015/02/06/parsing-binary-protocol-data-javascript-typedarrays-blobs/)